How to customize Spring Cloud Stream Schema Registry to work with No SQL backend
I am trying to integrate Spring Cloud Stream Schema Registry with MongoDB as the Schema Registry backend. I just want to know with the current implementation will this be feasible and what kinds of changes will be required to achieve this?
I have gone through the Spring Cloud Stream Schema Registry Core part and it seems lot of core changes needs to be done to achieve this.

Why not use a schema registry that's backed by kafka? What do you hope to gain from mongodb?

Yes, I understand something like confluent Schema registry is the best approach. We are exploring on Spring one for the time being.
We wanted to utilize one Database for the overall architecture Mongo is the one we have chosen already. That is why we are exploring the feasibility of Mongo for this.

Then you'll need to write the implementation for it, as I'm afraid there's no such option.


We wanted to utilize one Database for the overall architecture Mongo is the one we have chosen already

MongoDB is not a one-size-fits-all database, regardless of how they market their product.
Besides, Confluent Schema Registry, or the native H2 database of the Spring Registry don't require any extra infrastructure, if that's your main concern. You could run the Confluent Registry directly on the brokers, in fact.
(I don't think the H2 database is persistent, or will scale across nodes for high availability, so I wouldn't personally pick it).
If you're concerned about Confluent Licensing, there's other options like Apicurio, or Aiven Karapace, or AWS Glue Registry...

with the current implementation will this be feasible

The documentation is pretty explicit about your options of:

H2
MySQL (or compatible)
PostgreSQL (or compatible)
Confluent Schema Registry (or compatible)

MongoDB is not "compatible" with any clients for those databases.

what kinds of changes will be required to achieve this

You need a Collection schema for Mongo that can support, at the very least

Get-by-id
Get by "subject name"
Get by "version" of a "subject", where version is a non negative int or "latest"
Create "version" for "subject" that returns an ID

This can be built into a Kafka client library itself, it doesn't have to be "plugged into" any Registry product; that's primarily what all the Registries are providing - a native Kafka Serializer and Deserializer implementation around a simple REST or database client. (all mentioned options are open source, go take a look at implementation)

Yes, exactly. Licensing was one major concern we had with Confluence, which is why we were reluctant to pick It.
We decided to customise the Spring Schema Registry to support MongoDB. This approach allows us to change the database layer in the future if we want. Also to pick the default Message converters along with it.

The license mostly says you cannot host it as a paid solution to compete with Confluent Cloud Registry... As mentioned, there's other Apache 2.0 options ... Feel free to accept the answer using the checkmark if this answers your question
